# python eve hook,What should I do to not save this document when satisfying the conditions?

Tags: python, hook, eve

I have a hook function like

```
def before_insert(docs):
    for doc in docs:
        if doc['field'] == 'value':
           '''Do not save this document'''

app.on_insert_resource_name += before_insert
```

What should I do to not save this document when satisfying the conditions? Except for use `abort()`.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:

```
def before_insert(docs):
    docs = [doc for doc in docs if not doc['field'] == 'value']
```

Comment: But it's rarely a good idea to modify the structure you are iterating over; in this case the indices of all subsequent elements are reduced by one. You could mitigate this by building a list of indices to be removed then finally `del`ing them all starting with the highest. `for i in reversed(indices): del docs[i]`

Comment: @holdenweb PO use simple logic so i rewrite the answer, thank you for comment

Answer (score 1):

@holdenweb In fact this value is obtained from the database,

```
for doc in docs:
    res = db.collection.find_one ({"field": doc['field']})
    if res:
        ''' do not save this doc,
         i tried doc.clear() and del doc here ,but it not work.
          what shoud i do?'''
```

thanks for your comment.